# Inline images on mobile MJML

Tags: html, mailer, mjml

I am trying to create an email template using MJML. And I want to create an inline of images both on desktop and mobile. I wrote this code:

```
<mj-section background-color="#bce0a6">
       <mj-column>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
        <mj-image src="https://xxxx.png" alt="Twitter icon" width="24px" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"></mj-image>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
        <mj-image src="https://yyyy.png" alt="Instagram icon" width="24px" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"></mj-image>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
        <mj-image src="https://zzzz.png" alt="Pinteres icon" width="24px" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"></mj-image>
      </mj-column>
      <mj-column>
      </mj-column>
      <mj-column>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
```

This is the result in desktop version:
[image: This is the result in desktop version]
This is the result in mobile version:
[image: This is the result in mobile version]

I want to make the icon images inline as well on the mobile version WITHOUT using the `mj-social-element` that MJML has since I would like to use the icon images I have and not the icon images the `mj-social-element` offers.

Is there a way for me to do it? Thanks!

NOTE: In the code I used so 2 empty `<mj-column>` in the top and bottom so that the icons are centered but if there is another cleaner way to do it please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping it up in a `<mj-group>` did the trick:

```
    <mj-section background-color="#bce0a6">
      <mj-group>
       <mj-column>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
        <mj-image src="https://xxxx.png" alt="Twitter icon" width="24px" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"></mj-image>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
        <mj-image src="https://yyyy.png" alt="Instagram icon" width="24px" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"></mj-image>
       </mj-column>
       <mj-column>
        <mj-image src="https://zzzz.png" alt="Instagram icon" width="24px" padding-top="5px" padding-bottom="5px"></mj-image>
      </mj-column>
      <mj-column>
      </mj-column>
      <mj-column>
      </mj-column>
     </mj-group>
    </mj-section>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  <mj-social icon-padding="5px" icon-size="40px">
          <mj-social-element href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/02aae67d32c55468/943d32d4-61a8-4459-9091-daf7014d0769/64x64.png">
          </mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/02aae67d32c55468/4d5d6666-fd8c-4826-9e57-b8a70799cfba/64x64.png">
          </mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/02aae67d32c55468/3b59c8d5-afd9-4535-b269-fbb5d2449936/64x64.png">
          </mj-social-element>
</mj-social>
```

Comment: You can add custom images in the mjml social element tag